# Porque preciso fazer perguntas para aumentar minha reputação?

Tags: debate, perguntas, reputação

Porque preciso fazer perguntas para aumentar minha reputação e poder responder a outras perguntas?

Comment: Mas claro que por trás disso existem uma série de fatores em termos de experiência do usuário, engajamento e etc, que fazem o sistema ser como é, e vai mudar, mas detalhes que funcionam permanecem.

Comment: Ah, você pode com qualquer reputação responder a perguntas, só tem de esperar para comentaŕios, [chat] e outras funcionalidades, que nem os moderadores possuem (posso estar enganado).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não precisa de reputação alguma para responder.

Precisa para outras coisas, como pode ser visto na página de [privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

O sistema tem duas funções:

- Incentivar a participação positiva dos usuários através de [gamificação](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/).
- Estabelecer um parâmetro de confiança do usuário.

É verdade que ambos são falhos. O primeiro é abusado e muitas vezes incentiva a participação negativa, ou ainda quem não está nem aí pra isso, mas tem uma participação neutra, que acaba sendo negativa no sentido de que a pessoa não tem intenção de fazer parte da comunidade e contribuir, nem que seja com perguntas bem feitas que vão lhe ajudar diretamente.

Precisamos ter mecanismo para combater o *spam*, o usuário aloprado, *troll*, ou que ainda não entende bem o funcionamento do site, a cultura da comunidade. Mas claro, algumas coisas podem mudar.

O segundo é falho porque essa métrica de confiança não é precisa. Tem usuários que estão no site há anos, com reputações altas e não sabem usar e/ou não ligam por aprender usar o site, o que é bem triste. Mais ainda, há um problema que privilégios são liberados para quem não tem condição de usá-lo e tem histórico de causar problemas naquele item específico.

Não tem como fazer algo perfeito, mas pode-se aperfeiçoar muito. Dá um pouco de trabalho, abala as estruturas e desagrada alguns, o sistema fica um pouco mais complexo internamente, e ligeiramente mais externamente, porém com benefícios colaterais que compensam com folga, e talvez, só talvez fique uma pitadinha mais lento pra responder a requisição ao servidor, nada crítico, mas que também é compensado com uma melhor experiência do usuário, afinal performance é UX, sem dúvida, mas exagero de foco nisto deteriora a UX em outros pontos.

Se não quiser ter participação mais ativa não precisa de reputação.

A reputação indica muito o quanto o usuário contribui com a comunidade. Costuma ter uma pequena correlação em alguns casos com a capacidade técnica e de comunicação do usuário, mas não diretamente. Uma pessoa com 100K não é necessariamente 10X melhor que uma com 10K. E uma com 10K pode ser bem pior que uma de 1 ponto. Eu sou disparado o usuário de maior reputação no momento e tem jeito de ficar assim por um bom tempo, mas nem de longe sou o melhor desenvolvedor do site. Tem muita gente boa com reputações altas, ou mesmo baixas. Tem gente que, sinceramente, não deveria estar tão facilmente [nessa página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) e só não digo que é o meu caso porque contribuo muito. Então não podemos dizer que a reputação é um certificado de competência.

Comment: Entendi. Na verdade o motivo geral da pergunta era aumentar minha reputação. Muitas vezes utilizo o stack e encontro uma resposta que solucionam um problema meu, consequentemente quero votar e avaliar a mesma. Mas por não ter reputação, não consigo.

Comment: É a tal da confiança. Na verdade eu acho que deveria ser até mais restrito, só pode votar quem tem respostas boas dadas na *tag* (com alguns *escapes*)